# How to disable Safari's Live Text in my website?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, safari, frontend

I am making a Vue application and in the navbar I have a logo that when you click it, it sends you to the home page.

The logo is a `.svg` with the name of site, which has two lines. Lets say the website is called HelloWorld.com and the logo is kinda like this:

***hello***

***world.com***

In Safari, the [Live Text](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/interact-with-text-in-a-picture-ibrw20183ad7/mac) shows up (something like [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/interact-with-text-in-a-photo-using-live-text-pht6bc6bd5f5/mac)) and adds a layer that can send the user to world.com, which is not the best user experience.

Is there any way to disable this from Vue, HTML, CSS?

I have tried using this attributes to my img tag:

```
<img
@click="goToHome()" 
class="img-logo-navbar" 
src="/imgs/logo-RCN-black.svg"
style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;-o-user-select:none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;" 
unselectable="on"
onselectstart="return false;"
onmousedown="return false;"
/>
```

Comment: Althought it doesn't *really* disable LiveText, you can hide it by adding a `cursor: pointer` CSS rule to the bounding element (`<a>` or other) that will handle the link. I had the same problem and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet fixed it for me. It seems to overlap with stuff you've already tried, so Safari might have added code that now respects `-webkit-user-select` =)

```css
#myContainer img {
  // Disable text selection for Safari Live Text
  -webkit-user-select: none !important;
  cursor: default;
}
```